# Ajax get select tag id for passing through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

[select id section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT34D.jpg)

[script section in head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43SdZ.jpg)
So this is the situation.
I have this

```html
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)" id="1">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="'.$lectures[4][0].'">'.$lectures[4][0].'</option>
  <option value="'.$lectures[5][0].'">'.$lectures[5][0].'</option>
  <option value="'.$lectures[6][0].'">'.$lectures[6][0].'</option>
  <option value="'.$lectures[7][0].'">'.$lectures[7][0].'</option>
  </select>
```

Like this I have lots of select element in the page. I want to pass two value through ajax.
One is selected option value. Which I have done successfully.

**Other is the I want to pass select tag id. In this case it is 1.**

So Could you help me in the ajax part

```
  xmlhttp.open("GET","optiondetails.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

How to pass this value through ajax. Please keep in mind that I have to do this for many select tag. So I cannot pass them directly by value.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('select').change(function(){
   var opt = $(this).find('option:selected');
    console.log(opt.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="1">
<option value="dog">dog</option>
<option value="cat">cat</option>
</select>

<select id="2">
<option value="chocolate">chocolate</option>
<option value="pizza">pizza</option>
</select>
```

I used jQuery selector to get the selected option inside the changed select element

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So I can pass value from opt variable.  Would You please explain this  console.log(opt.val());

Comment: sure... it just logs it to the console... if you use chrome you can open the inspector by clicking right click and then inspect/inspect element, go to the console and you'll see the value right there. you can also use alert instead of console.log

Comment: Please let me bother you again. I am getting no results. No errors are being shown. Can you please tell me where do I need to put the above code. I have currently put it in head tag under the function which is taking this.value from select id

Comment: please attach a screenshot.

Comment: I have provided the screen shot of the current code. Please have a look on them. Nothing is working and no errors are being shown. Thanks

Comment: remove the onchange from the select tag and move the document ready outside of the show user function

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more convenient way to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
    var optVal = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "optiondetails.php",
        data: {q:optval, tag_id:id},
        cache: false
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. I need to pass two variable as stated in the question. could you help me more?

Comment: Of course. Just change here `data: {q:optval, anotherVariable : anotherValue}`

Comment: In which section I have to put this?

Comment: @PushkarKathayat, put the code before the `</body>` tag . Did you load `jquery` file ?

Comment: No. I have not loaded jquery file. I am using select tag in php. I am not getting which jquery file you are referring to?

Comment: @PushkarKathayat, you've loaded `jquery` library in the `<head>` section. Now just use this code before `</body>` tag.